# Ambiguity in static polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Quite a simple question actually but one which is bugging me a lot and I'm unable to find a sound answer for it.

How is the function call `d.show();` NOT ambiguous for the following code AND why does `b->show();` after `b = &d;` leads to the calling of `Base_::show()`?

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class Base_
{

     public:
          void show()
          {
               cout<<"\nBase Show";
          }
};

class Derived_ : public Base_
{
     public:
          void show()
          {    
              cout<<"Derived Show"<<endl;
          }     
};

int main()
{
     Base_ b;
     Derived_ d;
     b->show(); 
     d.show();
}
```

Comment: BTW, you can call Base class's `show()` by writing `d.Base_::show();`

Answer (score 1):

This is called "Name Hiding" in C++. Essentially, if a class defines a function, it hides all functions with the same name from parent classes. Also worth noting, if you had a `Base_*` to a derived object, and called that function, it would call the base classes version as it is not virtual and will not attempt to find overrided implementations in derived classes.

Comment: _"Also worth noting, if you had a Base_* to a derived object, and called that function, it would call the base classes version as it is not virtual and will not attempt to find overrided implementations in derived classes"_ **Is that because of name hiding too?**