# Ambiguity in Static Polymorphism part2

Tags: c++, polymorphism

With regards to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32655535/1977152), why doesn't a non-virtual method of the base class gets "name-hidden" when called via a base class pointer pointing to a derived object? I have edited that post to explain what my doubt is but haven't got any response from the fella who answered my [previous doubt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655484/ambiguity-in-static-polymorphism/32655535#32655535).

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with name hiding. In the C++ object model an object contains the following: the members (member variables and member functions, the latter occupying no "space"), and, if there is at least one member function is marked `virtual`, a pointer to the table of virtual functions. Whenever you have something like `Base* p = new Derived; p->f();`, the compiler proceeds in one of the two possible ways:

1. If `f` is marked virtual, the call is translated to `p->vpointer[index_of_f_in_vtable]();`, i.e. `f` is called via the pointer to vtable, which has the effect of invoking `Derived::f()`;
2. If `f` is not virtual, `Base::f()` is invoked since the pointer is of type `Base`.

In your case, there is no virtual table, so `Base::f()` is invoked.

See e.g. [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: So the "name hiding" concept(where the derived class method overrides base class method having the same name) doesn't applies here?

Comment: @KhanZaid No, it does not apply here. In the call `p->f();`, the function `f` must be common to both the Base and Derived, with exactly the same signature (up to [covariance of the return type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260757/when-is-c-covariance-the-best-solution)).